# mvn clean package, I want to copy the created jar to the current directory

Tags: maven

I want to update my pom.xml so that when someone uses: mvn clean package, the generated jar file is copied to the current directory. I'm looking at the maven plugin copy-resources, but i'm not sure how to specify the current directory, is there an operating system agnostic way to do this? Would like it to also work on windows, if possible

```
<plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <!-- here the phase you need -->
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>target/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Thanks

Comment: This might seem like a good idea, but it's really not.  As you may have noticed, the name of the artifact changes every time you change the version. Also, what about jars that are also built like sources and javadoc?

Comment: Just fix the name of your artifact with <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by current directory you mean `${project.basedir}` then yes you can do this easily. Just make sure you use `${build.finalName}.jar` as the file name part as it will properly get the main artifact of a project with `<packaging>` set to `jar` (the default).

```
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
         <!-- here the phase you need -->
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <!-- Get main artifact -->
          <directory>target/${build.finalName}.jar</directory>
          <!-- Don't filter binary files -->
          <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
      </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
```

If you wanted to do the current working directory instead you should be able to do it using `${user.dir}` as the `outputDirectory`

Comment: For me, this fails with "basedir ... .jar is not a directory". Removing the "/${build.finalName}.jar" from <directory> and adding `<includes><include>**/${build.finalName}.jar</include></includes>` inside the `<resource>` works. Thanks for putting me on the right track!!

Comment: plugin is run when target folder doesn't exist yet. I'm getting the following message: --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:copy-resources (copy-files-on-build) @ web-server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory .../web/web-server/target and nothing gets copied

Comment: @delucasvb Your comment was helpful. Just so it's obvious (I did this wrong first time), don't remove the `directory` element, just remove the filename from it and move it to it's own `<includes><include>${project.build.finalName}</include></includes>`. Without the `directory` element the plugin fails with the most cryptic of error stacktraces... :(

Comment: `${build.finalName}` is deprecated BTW in favor of `${project.build.finalName}`